# Cannot get back submitted data from select component in React Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, antd

I'm using `antd` to develop a form. But I couldn't get the value from my own defined `select` component. For other `antd` component like `Input`, there's no problem getting back the data.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-hooks-select-coler

In this form, the `Input` work properly, but the `Select` doesn't work.

Could anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass props to ant component.

```
const FileTypeSelect = (props) => {

  const Options = allFileTypes.map(Obj => (
    <Option value={Obj.typeId} key={Obj.typeId}>
      {Obj.fileType}
    </Option>
  ));

  return <Select {...props} placeholder="Select a File Type">{Options}</Select>;
};
```